# solc compiler --allow-paths fails

Tags: solc, solidity-0.6.x, cli

I'm trying to compile a contract using standard JSON through a script via the `solc` compiler CLI. I have a folder structure for storing the .sol files, the input JSON, and the compiled JSON output. No matter what variation I use in --allow-paths it tells me the file does not exist, yet if I open the supposedly non-existent file in `vim` it opens just fine.

I know the problem is with the `--allow-paths` argument, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Say the folder structure is:

- `/var/www/html/path/to/file/sub/test.sol` for Solidity files
- `/var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json` for input JSON files
- `/var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json` for compiled JSON files

The commands I've tried are:

- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths "/var/www/html/path/to/file/sub/" < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths /var/www/html/path/to/file/sub/ < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths "/var/www/html/path/to/file/sub" < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths /var/www/html/path/to/file/sub < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths "/var/www/html/path/to/file" < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- `solc --standard-json --allow-paths /var/www/html/path/to/file < /var/www/html/path/to/input/sub/input.json > /var/www/html/path/to/compiled/sub/compiled.json`
- all variations above using relative paths instead from `/var/www/html/path`

I've verified multiple times that the path to the Solidity file in the input JSON is correct, but no matter what I try I keep getting a file not found error:

```
{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Cannot import url (\"/var/www/html/path/to/file/sub/test.sol\"): File not found.","message":"Cannot import url (\"/var/www/html/path/to/file/sub/test.sol\"): File not found.","severity":"error","type":"IOError"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it clear, but even with --allow-paths solc will still not look outside the home directory and it's subs and the install folder for solc.

Therefore, I had to create a new user and use that users home directory, and things worked fine.